# Springboot, how to handle association class with a map?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a Restaurant management program. I have 2 entities: Order and Dish.

What i have in mind is that an Order is composed by an Id, a Table and a collection that must store the informations about every Dish for that order. For example, informations about the quantity and the state of the dish (an enumeration with values "to prepare", "preparing", "completed").

To accomplish this, i thought i could use a map, so every Order has a map with Dish as key, and a class called "DishInfo" as value, in which there are stored the quantity of that dish for that specific order, and the state of preparation of the dish.

I'm doing this because in the end i want a table which stores the following informations:
IdOrder, IdDish, Quantity, Status.

For example:

```
Order_12, Dish_14, 2, TO_PREPARE
```

Using a map seems reasonable, but since this table has 2 foreign keys, the IdOrder and IdDish, so it must be an association class. In fact, Order and Dish have a OneToMany relation with each other: an Order could have 1 or more Dishes, and a Dish could belong to 1 or many Orders. So, this being an association class is logic.

Now comes my question: i'm developing this backend using Springboot, and it's the first time i'm facing a solution which involves a Map that in reality reprehesents an association class. Does my reasoning make sense? Because from my studies i understood that when you have an association class, each of the two entities must have a List of the class that reprehesents the association class (i think).

To let you understand better, i'll post my code here, so that you can eventually find out errors. Thank you in advance.

Order Class

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;import jakarta.persistence.*;import java.util.HashMap;import java.util.Map;

@Entity
@Table
public class Order {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
                       name = "order_sequence",
                       sequenceName = "order_sequence",
                       allocationSize = 1
                      )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "order_sequence"
            )
    private Long idOrder;
    String table;
    @OneToMany
    Map<Dish, DishInfo> infoOrder;
    private boolean completed = false;

    public Order(Long idOrder, String table) {
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
        this.table = table;
        this.infoOrder = new HashMap<>();    }


    public void addDish(Dish dish, Integer quantity){
        DishInfo info = new DishInfo(quantity, DishInfo.OrderStatus.TO_PREPARE);        infoOrder.put(piatto, info);    }

}
```

Dish Class

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;import jakarta.persistence.*;import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

@Entity
@Table
public class Dish {
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "dish_sequence",
            sequenceName = "dish_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
 )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
             generator = "dish_sequence"
)

    private Long idDish;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String allergics;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "idCategory",
            referencedColumnName = "idCategory"    )

    private Category category;
    private float price;

// Constructor...

}
```

InfoOrder class

```
package com.springone3.demo.Entity;import jakarta.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table
public class InfoDish {

    @Id    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("idOrder")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_order")
    private Order order;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("idDish")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_dish")
    private Dish dish;

    private int quantity;
    private OrderStatus;

public InfoDish(int quantity, OrderStatus status) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.status = status;
}

   
    public void setStatus(OrderStatus status) {
        this.status = status;    }

    public enum OrderStatus{
        TO_PREPARE,
        PREPARING,
        COMPLETED;
}
}
```

This is the code i did for now, i didn't compile it yet because i want to be sure that i'm on the right track, since it is a delicate topic.